# ADT not getting applied in Eclips

Tags: android, adt

I have installed latest ADT and SDK 22.6.2

whenever I check from Help->Install New software

It says it's already installed...

then why eclips shows error:
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

It is already downloaded via https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

but still shows...
please help

Answer (score 1):

Check updates for Eclipse when the update is finished, then restart the IDE.

However I suggest you to use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) (IntelliJ IDEA Based). Isn't a final version but is yet more stable then Eclipse for Android development.

Comment: mmm...Try to remove and reinstall ADT Plugin